# Ошибка при чтении символов строки С++

Tags: массивы, строки, файлы, динамические-массивы

Нужно считать данные с файла в строки, а потом разделить строку на слова и записать в двумерный динамический массив. В первую строку слова записываются без проблем, а когда доходит до второй строки отладчик выдаёт "ошибка чтения символов строки". Подскажите пожалуйста в чём может быть проблема. Заранее спасибо)

Auto.txt :

```
chevrolet,aveo,седан,AX2857KA,исправен
daewoo,lanos,седан,AX2349BR,исправен
volkswagen,passat,седан,AX9127LP,исправен
mercedes,vito,микроавтобус,AX6098AE,исправен
toyota,rav4,кросовер,AX1936FN,исправен
chevrolet,aveo,седан,AX6289KP,неисправен
daewoo,lanos,седан,AX2837JN,неисправен
volkswagen,passat,седан,AX2578BI,исправен
mercedes,vito,микроавтобус,AX0378HP,исправен
toyota,rav4,кросовер,AX9247PU,исправен
```

Основной код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int CountOfStrings(string filename)
{
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(filename);
    string str;
    int i = 0;
    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        getline(fin, str);
        i++;
    }
    fin.close();
    return i;
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int size = CountOfStrings("Auto.txt");
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("Auto.txt");
    string** arr = new string * [size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new string[5];
    }
    for (int object = 0; object < size; object++)
    {
        for (int field = 0; field < 5; field++)
        {
            arr[object][field] = "";
        }
    }

    string token;
    int field = -1, object = -1;
    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        ++object;
        string myText("");
        getline(fin, myText);
        istringstream iss(myText);
        string token;
        while (getline(iss, token, ','))
        {
            ++field;
            arr[object][field] = token;
            cout << token<<" ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
        delete[] arr[count];
    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в была в том, что я выходил за пределы массива.
Вот корректно работающий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int CountOfStrings(string filename)
{
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(filename);
    int i = 0;
    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        getline(fin, str);
        i++;
    }
    fin.close();
    return i;
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int size = CountOfStrings("Auto.txt");
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("Auto.txt");
    string** arr = new string * [size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new string[5];
    }
    for (int object = 0; object < size; object++)
    {
        for (int field = 0; field < 5; field++)
        {
            arr[object][field] = "";
        }
    }
    int object = -1;
    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        ++object;
        string myText("");
        getline(fin, myText);
        istringstream iss(myText);
        string token = "";
        int field = -1;
        while (getline(iss, token, ','))
        {
            ++field;
            arr[object][field] = token;
            cout << token<<" ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
        delete[] arr[count];
    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```